# WinRT/C++ Get parent Page control of the Page inside the Frame

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-winrt

Best way to get parent Page control from Page inside Frame on desktop application built with WinRT/C++ UI.

Illustration:

```
MainPage
    ^^Frame
        ^^SecondPage
            ^^Frame
                ^^ThirdPage
                    ^^Keep going
```

So, how to get MainPage control from SecondPage or even from ThirdPage onwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`VisualTreeHelper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper) to navigate the visual tree. The following implementation goes up the visual tree starting at a `root` element, and returns an element that matches the requested `ancestor_type`, or a null `com_ptr` if there isn't any that matches:

```cpp
template <typename ancestor_type>
auto find_ancestor(::winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::DependencyObject root) noexcept
{
    auto ancestor { root.try_as<ancestor_type>() };
    while (!ancestor && root)
    {
        root = ::winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::VisualTreeHelper::GetParent(root);
        ancestor = root.try_as<ancestor_type>();
    }
    return ancestor;
}
```

You can use this to move from `Page` to `Page`, skipping over the intermediate `Frame`'s until you are at the top of the tree.