# Get app HWND from UIElement section Xaml Island WinRT/C++

Tags: winrt-xaml, c++-winrt, xaml-islands

How to get the HWND part used for hosting the UIElement from a UWP project on a XamlIsland WinRT/C++ based application? The HWND I mean can be:

1. Desktop application
2. Window or other UI element (HWND)
3. Internal native window (HWND)

[image]

Comment: Can we iterate over the parent of a UIElement until we get `DesktopWindowXamlSource` and call the `.as<IDesktopWindowXamlSourceNative>().get_WindowHandle(&hwnd)` method?

Comment: I'm guessing that's a feasible approach. See if the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70363785/1889329) works for navigating up to the next `DesktopWindowXamlSource`.